# I want rotational ID limit

Tags: php, sql, database

I am selecting data from a database. I have 105 records in my database table and I want at a time only 10 records from that. when I fetch record next time I want records from attempted records to next 10 records. for that, I have made query given below.

```
$attempt = '10';

$tbl_quickten ="SELECT * FROM `tbl_quickten` WHERE `ID` BETWEEN '$attempt' AND '100' LIMIT 10";
$tbl_quickten_result = mysqli_query($con,$tbl_quickten);
$array = mysqli_fetch_all($tbl_quickten_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

it is working fine but when I fetch 100 records and again hit my query I want records from 100-105 and also 1-5.

I have no idea how can I fetch these records rotationally.

can anybody help me in this.

Comment: You’re gonna need to modify your WHERE clause in that case, so that it selects records with ID <= 5 as well.

Comment: actually, I want to use this query for so many tables dynamically and these 105 records are virtual I assume that so is there any way to make this dynamically?

Comment: and also I have to fetch records at a time 10 only I can not modify that.

Comment: Then combine your query that tries to select X records from the current “position” with one that selects the _first_ X records via UNION, and limit the result of that complete union to X again.

Comment: @misorude can you please show me the example of a query? so I can understand it better.

Comment: You code is vulnerable to SQL Injection: *always* parameterise your queries!

Comment: @misorude not about UNION but can you please explain what you write again because it is little confusing.

Comment: Write one query that gets a maximum of 10 records from your current position to the end, and a second one that gets the first 10 records. Combine both results via UNION, and apply the limit of 10 to the result of that again. If your first query returned a full ten records, then this is what you get returned; if not, then the second query will “fill it up” with records from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, you don't want a `where` clause, only an `order by`:

```
SELECT qt.*
FROM `tbl_quickten` 
ORDER BY (id >= ?) DESC,  -- put bigger ids first
         id ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Note the use of `?`.  This is a *parameter placeholder*.  You should be using parameters rather than munging the query string with such values.